# Get the the page url from Page GUID

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-page

I have a list of publishing page's Guids which are from different sites, I want to get the page properties like URL, Title and content type from that GUID. Is there any way we can do it in code behind?

Preferably not loop through each site considering performance factor.

Comment: did you check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709212/get-site-url-based-on-guid-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

```
 static string GetUrlByGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        var item = SPFarm.Local.GetObject(guid);
        if (item == null) 
            return null;
        return item.ToString(); //return item.Url or something like it
    }
```

Refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709212/get-site-url-based-on-guid-sharepoint